# hanging indent conflict with section space

Tags: sections-paragraphs

In some parts of my document, I want to have hanging indent on paragraphs.  I noticed that the section space gets messed up when I use \hangparas.  Compared to other sections in the document, there is less vertical space between sections when I use the hanging package.  How do I keep the same space between sections while using \hangparas ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\itshape\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document} 

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\textsc{Some Chapter}}

\section{Section w No Hanging}

\blindtext

\blindtext


\section{Section w Hanging}

\begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{hangparas}

\section{Next Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hangparas` environment just after the section title doesn't reset `\if@nobreak` to false, because it changes `\everypar` before `\@nobreakfalse` is executed.

We can make it not ignore it.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\itshape\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\makeatletter
\def\hangparas#1#2{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}%
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
    \fi
    \everypar{\hangpara{#1}{#2}}%
    \hangpara{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}

%\def\endhangparas{\par\@nobreakfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\textsc{Some Chapter}}

\section{Section w No Hanging}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{Section w Hanging}

\begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{hangparas}

\section{Next Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  That's over my head, but it works.  Thank you very much.